# pg_stat_statements slows down the database

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora, pg-stat-statements

I have an aws aurora postgresql cluster running posgresql 13.7 engine. The cluster is using the default parameter group.

These are the default settings used for pg_stat_statements in the parameter group (i use the default parameter group - this exact one, for other clusters as well).
[image: pg_stat_statements in parameter group]
Basically nothing is changed from the default values.

I use multiple glue jobs to write to this aurora cluster and I encounter an issue with the pg_stat_statement waits after a couple of runs.

If i do nothing about it, the cluster will automatically restart stating that the database processes have been killed due to the long runtime.

If i restart the cluster or if i use

```
SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset();
```

The pg_stat_statements view gets a reset and everything runs as it should.

Note: if the database gets restarted, right after restart i can run the same load (exactly the one that failed) with no issues.

Note2: I have another cluster with the same settings (size and parameter group), running the same type of jobs that does not manifest like this.

Example run1 - LWLock:pg_stat_statements in blue
[image]

Example run2 - LWLock:pg_stat_statements in yellow
[image]

I already adapted my glue jobs to be less stressful for the cluster by lowering the number of dpu's and implicitly running less parralel inserts into it.

Any ideas regarding where i should pick this up from are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off/ setting zero for all the pg_stat_statements parameters in the parameter group. I had the same problem and this fixed the issue.
Also see the related issue [pg_stat_statements causing DB to run out of memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186852/pg-stat-statements-causing-db-to-run-out-of-memory)

Comment: Please post the essential parts of your answer here. Links can disappear.

Comment: I actually managed to fix this by setting the pg_stat_statements.max to 100 instead of keeping the default value. Thank you very much for the link, i will also post my findings there as a link. The issue was that i am using glue to upsert data using psycopg2 - i have a big table with a lot of data and i have to split the insert statements - that would cause BIG insert statements that are writtent in parallel and i think here is where pg_stat_statements started complaining.